# show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{e^n}$ implies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{S_n}{e^n}$ where $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{e^n}$$ is convergent

denote$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_n$$

show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{S_n}{e^n}$$ is convergent.

Comment: Just to clarify, $e=\ln(1)$ here, right? Its a constant?

Comment: @icurays1 Rather $\ln e=1$.

Comment: Ha, whoops.  Coffee hasn't kicked in yet.  Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: yes, $e$ means euler constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Abel's identity to show that:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{S_n}{e^n}=1/(e^{-1}-1)[e^{-(k+1)}S_{k+1}-e^{-1}S_1-\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{a_{n+1}}{e^{n+1}}]$$

Now the answer to your question follows very easily because the limit of the right hand side exists.

Comment: +1 for nice argument! I want to comment that though the convergence of $S_{k} e^{-k}$ follows from Cesaro-Stolz theorem together with the observation $a_n = o(e^n)$, it still seems to deserve a justification when it comes to elementary level analysis.